# Flex invalid session error

Tags: actionscript-3, tomcat, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

Am trying to call a service running in tomcat through remote objects from flex, when i call the remote object it throws flex invalid session error

```
Channel.Ping.Failed error There was an unhandled failure on the server. The FlexSession is invalid. url: 'http://localhost:8080/Server/messagebroker/amf/'
[RemoteObject  destination="reinforcementService" channelSet="[ChannelSet null ]"]
Send failed
```

Code

```
<s:CallResponder id="getReinforcementsResult"/>
        <services:ReinforcementService id="reinforcementService" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>

<s:RemoteObject id="ro2" destination="reinforcementService"  endpoint="{parentApplication.serviceURL}" result="ro2_resultHandler(event)" fault="ro2_faultHandler(event)"/>
```

and i call the method using

```
ro2.getReinforcements();
```

and i disconnect the remote object in result handler to avoid DuplicateFlexSessions error

```
ro2.disconnect();
```

and the channel definition in services-config.xml is as follows

```
  <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
       <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
       <properties>
        <polling-enabled>true</polling-enabled>
        <add-no-cache-headers>true</add-no-cache-headers>
        <!-- <invalidate-session-on-disconnect>true</invalidate-session-on-disconnect> -->
        <invalidate-session-on-disconnect>true</invalidate-session-on-disconnect>
</properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using spring security? Did you try to login using the channelset? there is a login() function on the channelset, used to login. Later you can set this channelset to the remote object to invoke the serves.

Comment: instead of defining the channel on the services-config, you can create one in the client itself.